# How Many Virtual Table Lookups Occur?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Consider the following example

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void Interface() = 0;
  virtual ~Base() {};

protected:
  int Identify() { return SubclassesMustImplement(); }

private:
  virtual int SubclassesMustImplement() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void Interface() override { std::cout << Identify() << std::endl; };

private:
  int SubclassesMustImplement() final { return 42; };
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  Base* b = &d;
  b->Interface();
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how many virtual table lookups occur here. The first one occurs at `b->Interface()` which resolves to `Derived::Interface`. What I am not sure about is if a second virtual table lookup ever occurs. In the body of `Derived::Interface`, `Identify()` is not virtual so it is known at compile-time to be `Base::Identify()`. However, in the body of `Base::Interface()` we call `SubclassesMustImplement()`. At this point in the code, is the `this` pointer referring to a `Base` or `Derived`?

If it is pointing to a `Base`, then a virtual table lookup (ignoring compiler optimizations for a simple case like this) will occur. If it is pointing to a `Derived`, then `final` means that no virtual table lookup occurs.

Comment: Is this just for academic understanding, or because of a measurable performance problem? Have you had a look at the generated assembly code?

Comment: Academic understanding. I am mostly curious how `this` is defined when entering a function call of a base class.

Comment: There might be no vtable lookups at runtime if everything gets inlined and optimized away.  The lookups are still occurring, they just occur at compile time.

Comment: The standard doesn't require that an implementation use a virtual function table at all (a vtable is a common implementation choice, but the standard doesn't require it).   In your example, there are two virtual function calls, in the sense of two function calls that resolve to a function determined by actual type of the object.  The call of `b->Interface()` will call `Derived::Interface()`, and the call of `Identity()` will call `Derived::SubClassesMustImplement()`.   How that effect is achieved is unspecified by the standard (i.e. the implementation can do what it likes).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the standard has too much to say about this, but in practise:

> in the body of `Base::Interface()` we call `SubclassesMustImplement()`. At this point in the code, is the `this` pointer referring to a `Base` or `Derived`?

`Derived`.  Multiple inheritance excepted, `this` never changes.

> If it is pointing to a `Base`, then a virtual table lookup (ignoring compiler optimizations for a simple case like this) will occur. If it is pointing to a `Derived`, then `final` means that no virtual table lookup occurs.

I don't think you can conclude that (although the compiler might be able to figure it out when the call to `Identify` can be inlined - you'd have to inspect the generated code at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) to check.  If you do this, make sure that optimisations are enabled).

In general,  when the compiler generates code for a function body, it neither knows nor cares what type of object `this` will be pointing to when the function is actually called.  Indeed, that is the whole point of using `virtual` functions.  But in this case, your use of pure virtual functions, functions marked `final`, and function bodies implemented in the class declaration complicates things a bit (and I for one can't predict with any certainty what the compiler will make of all that).